Terraform apply appears to create a cloudfoundry_network_policy resource, but actually does not
I am using Terraform to create a CloudFoundry Network Policy, following the documentation. The purpose of this is container-to-container networking.
My Terraform HCL code looks like this:
resource "cloudfoundry_network_policy" "my-policy" {

  policy {
    source_app = "source-app-name"
    destination_app = "destination-app-name"
    port = "8080"
  }
}

When I run terraform apply it all appears to work fine. But it does not actually create  the policy. Apply again and Terraform will try to create the policy again, as though it never existed:
~ resource "cloudfoundry_network_policy" "my-policy" {
      id = "some-GUID-here"

    + policy {
        + destination_app = "destination-app-name"
        + port            = "8080"
        + protocol        = "tcp"
        + source_app      = "source-app-name"
      }
  }

It will do this an indefinite number of times, never raising an error, but never actually creating the Policy. The command cf network-policies shows no new policies at any point.
I have found that it does not matter what app names I use. Fake names like destination-app-name produce the same outcome: appearing to be applied, actually creating nothing. So, I assume errors are getting swallowed somewhere. Presumably a totally fake app name should fail and should produce an error, somewhere.
Where can I look for the errors? How do I make a working cloudfoundry_network_policy resource?

If you run terraform plan -refresh-only after a successful terraform apply, does it report that anything has "changed outside of Terraform"? I'm wondering if the provider is confusing itself by dropping that policy block when it refreshes, making it seem like it needs to be added again by the next plan.

The link to the provider shows that's very old (4 years). Would you be able to use this one instead: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudfoundry-community/cloudfoundry/latest/docs/resources/network_policy?

Oops, thank you @MarkoE, I linked to the wrong documentation. The link you just shared is actually the one I am using. I have edited my question.
